# Как в jQuery определить по элементу его номер в выборке?

Tags: jquery

Например, есть выборка списка (тегов li). По клику на элемент (li) мы вылавливаем его с помощью this, а далее как узнать на какой элемент по счету мы кликнули?

Comment: как вариант пронумеровать их программно добавив какой нибудь атрибут, например data-num, а потом просто его считывать. Но может если более изящное решение?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[$.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
var $set = $('ul li');
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var n=$set.index(this);    
    console.log(n);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zLZg2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert( $( this ).index() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KBsSU/

Comment: посмотрите, так он просто среди сиблингов индекс выдает, а не из списка могут быть проблемы:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KBsSU/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KBsSU/1/

Comment: Спасибо за пример! Думал что в пределах одного списка нужен индекс элемента.